# How to open a default listening port on gcp?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am using `ubuntu 18.04` in my GCP and have setup my firewalls to listen to port 5000 by default:
[image]

my output for `netstat -tupln`:
[image]

when I open `<my-ip-address>:5000` I can access my hosted website, but when I try to do `<my-ipaddress>` It says connection refused. I don't know why it says show as I have changed default port on firewall as well. Can someone please help me out here?

Answer (score 0):

when you open up the public address in a web browser it will go to the server looking for an application running on port 80 or 443 in case of https request. That is why the connection is refused because your firebase only allows for 5000 port request will be forward to your machine.

Comment: Hmm, so what change are you suggesting me to do? I am still confused to what you just said.

Comment: that depends on what you're looking to achieve. If you want to only use IP and not port address then update the docker to the server at 80 port. Add ingress traffic to port 80.
If you looking to run redash on a machine use this market place https://console.cloud.google.com/marketplace/browse?q=redash

Comment: Ok so I did that, I updated my `docker-compose.yml` to serve redash on `80` and nginx on `5000` and in that case even port `80` wasn't responding. My end goal is to only use IP. Can you please guide me little better. I have tried changing the port in docker-compose.yml. Do I need to change firewell rules too?

Comment: you did not mention Nginx before. Please revert the docker change and just open port 80 on the Firewall.

Comment: port 80 is already open in firewall... but after composing docker, it serves on port 5000.

Comment: Just to confirm, in `docker-compose.yml` we have redash on port 5000 and nginx proxy on 80 and firewall rule should have default-http to be 80 and default-https to be on 443 right? Do I need to add something else other than this?

Comment: Two possible solution 
1) Stop nginx and run docker on 80 port
2) Add a reverse proxy setting to Nginx to route 80 requests to 5000

Also check that services are running properly

Comment: Just to notify, my nginx is configured with docker. so you mean something like: docker-compose stop nginx and then change docker-compose update the redash port to 80 and nginx port to 5000?